# Does the Data Science process (CRISP ) comply with the Agile methodology?

Tags: methods

A common method for conduction data science projects is CRISP - https://www.datascience-pm.com/crisp-dm-2/.

However in job descriptions they are often combine data science with agile methods, mostly SCRUM.

How fits data science together with Agile, Scrum?

I get that CRISP and Scrum both use the cycle as a way to approach the end result, but there is a lot of different methodology and terminology.

Any ideas or hints for further readings?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, but I posted a similar question you may be interested in taking a look at: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/108511/whats-your-dream-work-environment/108674?noredirect=1#comment110614_108674

Comment: Thanks, certainly will :-)